# Ajax Form Not Working in some Some Regions

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I created an ajax based contact form in my module.Then I made a block view for the form. I tried putting that block to several regions. When I put the block to 'Sidebar Second' the form works as desired.But when I put the same block to 'contact' Region (custom region) , the form's ajax part does not work .

This is the code I used to print the block .

```
$contact = render(block_get_blocks_by_region('contact'));
print  $contact;
```

When I inspect the element the form-id is 'myform' as given by me . Still the ajax part is not working .

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this . Just want to tell  the answer for anyone who might come across this problem. The problem was :

I was printing it in `html.tpl.php`.

The solution is

print it on either `page.tpl.php` or `page--xxxx.tpl.php` and print it as

```
<?php 
     print render($page['contact']);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons which impact Form Ajax, would suggest check once below points

1. HTML structure after rendering from Sidebar Second
2. Is there any Javascript error in your page?
3. Refer https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2019-06-19/why-is-my-ajax-not-working

Comment: You do know this question is asked 8 years ago, right? :P Also, the OP provided his own answer.